# Choosing the correct DB2 drivers to get data acceleration

Tags: db2, driver

In order to connect to IBM DB2 from either Excel or a C# .net application, which driver do I need in order to also get the data acceleration? (set current query acceleration all;) Are there drivers that are portable (don't need admin rights to install)?

If they do need admin, I can always ask IT support to install it for me..

Have been using JDBC drivers for my Squirrel SQL client, and they support IBM IDAA (acceleration), but these won't work with Excel nor C#. Obviously.

Any pointers?

Comment: Could you add your Db2 version and platform? It seems you are using Db2 for z/OS and are interested in the IBM Db2 Analytics Accelerator (IDAA), right?

Comment: It is running on our mainframe on zOS, the DB2 version is v12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access Db2-for-Z/OS from either Excel or C# .net you will need a CLI driver for Db2 with matching bitness.

Depending on how your Db2-for-Z/OS subsystems are licensed you may also need a license-file on the Microsoft-windows workstation, becase IBM supplied CLI drivers are not free for accessing Db2-fo-Z/OS. Speak with your Z-DBA or passport-advantage-coordinator to get the license-file (and the correct version of it to match your version of Db2-for-Z/OS)  or to determine if the target subsystem has already db2connectactivate enabled ( meaning no workstation based licenses are required).

IBM and other companies offer CLI drivers for Db2 for various operating systems including Microsoft Windows.

IBM offers different sizes of CLI driver, depening on how much functionality you need.

Any of these should work with IDAA as long as they are "current", and the keywords needed for IDAA exploitation should be common between the IBM supplied CLI drivers.

The smallest footprint, minimal function, zero install CLI driver from IBM is the "ODBC and CLI" driver, which is a zipfile (just unzip and register it per the docs). Get it via this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-odbc-cli-driver-download-and-installation-information), and then install it per this [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=dsd-installing-data-server-driver-odbc-cli-software-windows-operating-systems).  Note that this driver gets frequently updated, as it is used by all CLI/ODBC based tools (perl, python, r, c#, ruby, c++, ...). It's also possible to use `wget` to download it. google for that.

A larger driver is the "Db2 runtime client", which has more functionality and the clpplus interface. This is available via the IBM Passport Advantage website , or via fix central for latest fixpacks.

The full Db2 client is a large image, and has all functionality that IBM offers for client side use. Get this via the IBM Passport Advantage website, or via fix central for latest fixpacks.

Comment: Thanks! I already use a license file (in fact two) along with the JDBC driver, so I guess it will be needed for the CLI drivers as well.  Not totally sure about the version of DB2, but that is a minor task to find out. (I'll ask the db admin).

Comment: As commented further up, it is DB2 version 12, on mainframe using zOS.